# split words by character with random length group jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to split words like that using javascript.

```
Fantastique

for {Fan,ta,s,tiq,ue}
```

I tried this:

```
$transss = "Fantastique";
var numberArray2 = $transss.match(/.{1,3}/g);

numberArray2.sort(function() {
  return 0.5 - Math.random();
});

$.each(numberArray2, function(k, v) {
  var buttons = $('<button class="btn btn-simple shortcut" value="" addspace="false" punctuatedword="' + v + '" data-index="' + k + '" lastbutton="true">' + v + '</button>') buttons.appendTo('.tool-box');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = 'Fantastique';
console.log(str.match(/.{1,3}/g));
```